# German sofa primes: Can both $q$ and $\frac{q^3+1}{2}$ be prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is there an odd prime integer $\displaystyle q$ such that $\displaystyle p= \frac{q^3+1}{2}$ is also prime?

A quick search did not find any, nor a pattern in the prime factorization of p.  This is a possible quick solution to the unitary and Ree cases of [ME.16954](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16954/what-are-the-subgroups-of-alt2p-containing-the-normalizer-of-a-sylow-p-subgroup).

Comment: Its not German sofa its **Sophie Germain**

Comment: Sophie Germain was much better with primes than me.  My numbers are more like a sectional sofa.  One section with 2, one with (q+1)/2, and one with (qq+q+1)/2.

Comment: I think you mean $(qq-q+1)/2$? Also, why are you factoring out $2$? $qq\pm q+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Isn't this divisble by $\displaystyle \frac{q+1}{2}$?