# What is the significance of 3-transitive Galois group

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

If the Galois group $G$ of a polynomial of degree $n$ is 3-transitive, what can we conclude from this? Is $G=S_n$, where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n$

Any Hint is useful.
Thanks

---

[relocated the following comments by the OP here, JL]

I was  reading [Topics in Galois Theory  by Serre](http://www.msc.uky.edu/sohum/ma561/notes/workspace/books/serre_galois_theory.pdf). In theorem 4.4.3., says Let G be a transitive subgroup of $S_n$, which contains transposition. Then TFAE. 1)$ G$ contains $(n-1)$ cycle, 2)$G$ is doubly transitive 3) $G=S_n$.

So was wondering does any such result exist for triple transitive?

Comment: The alternating group is 3-transitive for most $n$ ($n\ge 5$).

Comment: Questions are usually better-received here if you provide evidence of your own efforts and where you are stuck.

Comment: Every finite group can be realized as a Galois group of some extension of fields (conjecturally also as a Galois group $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$ but that is still open). Therefore it is a bit unclear what could be said. At least I don't see anything, but I'm not an expert on this. Also, because a Galois group can be seen as a permutation group in many ways (the said field extension is often the splitting field of many polynomials of varying degrees), it is a bit difficult to see how to take advantage. I'm not saying that nothing interesting would not be out there, but...

Comment: I once had the pleasure of attending a lecture by Abhyankar about realizing the 5-transitive Mathieu groups as Galois groups (in characteristic $p$). He used "derivatives" in some absolutely stunning way, but time has erased all the details from my brain.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, @ Producer of BS   I was  reading Topics in Galois Theory  by Serre [http://www.msc.uky.edu/sohum/ma561/notes/workspace/books/serre_galois_theory.pdf], In theorem 4.4.3., says Let G be a transitive subgroup of $S_n$, which contains transposition. Then TFAE. 1)$ G$ contains $(n-1)$ cycle, 2)$G$ is doubly transitive 3) $G=S_n$

Comment: So was wondering does any such result exist for triple transitive?

Comment: I see. Yes, that is a nice result on 2-transitivity. IIRC a highly transitive subgroup of $S_n$ relatively easily becomes all of $S_n$. Something along those lines was already in Burnside's century old book. Plenty of 2-transitive groups can be constructed from actions of linear groups on vector spaces (or more likely projective spaces). 3-transitivity is more difficult, not the least because while two distinct 1-d subspaces are always linearly independent three such things may or may not. This ruins the 3-transitivity of many a construction :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thank you

Comment: The finite 3-transitive groups have essentially been classified, using the classification of finite simple groups. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698327/) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222639/) for example.